Understanding [GoF] Decorator design pattern: detaching responsibilities dynamically without recreating the whole chain
So, in my understanding, with Decorator pattern you can easily attach additional "responsibilites" (or more generally, behaviors) to an object dynamically. Usually the decoration chain is started at the moment of the creation of objects, and then since both the object to decorate and its decorator implement the same interface, you can attach additional behavior easily as follows:
var someDecorator = theVariableToDecorate()

// do whatever

someDecorator = decoratedVariable(decorated: someDecorator)

Removing the last decorator is quite easy:
someDecorator = someDecorator.getDecorated()

An example for my doubt
Now assume that there is a more complex structure, for example imagine writing a program whose responsibility is to process some audio signal and display it via a spectrogram.
In this scenario, the basic behavior is to compute the FFT of a window of samples of fixed size (usually power of two), so the leaf of the decorator is some FFTStrategy object exposing a .transform(signal: [Double]) -> [Complex] just for the sake of this example (wanna avoid introducing vDSP specific types for the sake of simplicity).
Then the user might want to further transform the FFT of the input signal. Common transforms might include:

Apply some gain to the whole frequency spectrum (0Hz -> Nyquist frequency).
Convert the input signal to decibel with respect to some reference.
Apply filters, as low-pass, high-pass, band-pass, band-boost, a combination of the following.
Convert the frequency spectrum from linear scale to Mel scale (or the other way around)

In this context, there is a good chance that one could think of the previous as decorators to the .transform(signal: [Double]) -> [Complex] method, and create the following types:

FFTGainDecorator, whose initialiser accepts some gain value.
FFTDecibelDecorator, whose initialiser accepts a reference value.
FFTLowPassDecorator, FFTBandPassDecorator, FFTBandBoostDecorator, FFTHighPassDecorator, to be specified, maybe to have an unified initialiser let them accept an input of some type FFTFilterConfiguration.
FFTMelScaleDecorator, whose initialiser accepts the nyquist frequency and number of filterbanks.

This way one could easily have something like this:
let signalProcessor = FFTDecibelDecorator(
    reference: 20_000,
    decorated: FFTMelScaleDecorator(
        filterbanksCount: 16,
        decorated: FFTBandPassDecorator(
            passbandRipple: 1,
            stopbandRipple: 1,
            rolloffPerOctaveInDb: -48,
            passFrequency: 1800,
            stopFrequency: 2200,
            decorated: FFTStrategy(
                 radix: 2
                 windowSize: 2048,
                 overlap: 4
            )
        )    
    )
)

// collect sample in a window

let fftForThisWindow = signalProcessor.transform(samplesInThisWindow)

// use the FFT to append a single column to the spectrogram

The issue(s):
So, this approach in my mind has two main issues:

What if I would like the GUI to allow me to "turn on/off" decorators with components such as switches or segmented controls? What if I have a segmented control to switch between linear and Mel scale?

There are conditions of well-formedness that the structure of the classes in the decorator pattern can't enforce. For example it makes no sense that one can apply a filter after applying a Mel scale conversion. Or to be more exact, the code for the filter wouldn't be the same: the filter should be converted to Mel scale as well, which makes little sense in terms of efficiency (better to convert the result of the output than the signal and the filter then combining).


Further expanding point 1, there are only certain sequences in which decorators could appear, not every possible sequence is valid. I talked about this with my Software Engineering teacher and he said that he would solve problem 2 by introducing a new class whose responsibility is to validate a chain, that is, it exposes a .validate(decorator: FFTDecorator) -> Bool method that incapsulates the rules of well-formedness.
This validator though should be aware of the concrete type of each decorator or am I wrong? Maybe as an alternative one might create an enumeration
public enum FFTDecoratorType {
    case leaf
    case mel
    case lp
    case bp
    case hp
    case gain
    case decibel
}

And then prescribe that every decorator has a field instance var type: FFTDecoratorType {get} (thanks God Swift allows instance members on interfaces) that is privately set in the constructor of each decorator, then use it to perform the validation without tons of casts.
The other thing is: I'm quite sure I can't detach decorators without recreating the whole chain (would avoid, creating FFTSetup appears to be expensive and prone to memory leaks if one forgets to invoke vDSP_destroy_fftsetup).
But forcing the client to store reference to all the decorators and taking care of reconstructing the chain every time would be a great responsibility to add. Maybe it could be a good idea to introduce a further class whose responsibility is to create and install decorators, store their references and detach them, for instance segregating the decorators inside a package, making their constructors package-private (internal), and only allowing their instantiatione externally through this class.

These are both good questions and both are requirements the Decorator Pattern does not solve. The Decorator Pattern will make it harder to solve both of these requirements, as evidenced by the complex validation suggestion.
The answer then, is not to use the Decorator Pattern. A different pattern may help (perhaps something like the State Pattern) but more likely the requirements need a custom solution.
Typically with design-patterns questions, everyone is eager to suggest their favorite pattern and display their knowledge of that pattern. Resist these suggestions. Design Patterns are not the goal. Implement the requirements as best you can with concise, readable code. Perhaps that solution starts to look like a known pattern, but more than likely it does not, which is perfectly fine.

To allow one of the decorators to be dynamically enabled/disabled, it is enough to encapsulate some object in it that knows about the corresponding setting. Example (pseudocode):
// ConfiguredDecorator encapsulates a configuration object
class ConfiguredDecorator implements Decorator {

    Decorator decorator;
    Configuration configuration;

    ConfiguredDecorator(Decorator decorator,
                        Configuration configuration) {
        this.decorator = decorator;
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    void action() {
        if (configuration.isEnable()) {
            // do extra things
        } else {
            decorator.action();
        }
    }
}

// Switch component encapsulates the same configuration object
class Switch {

    Configuration configuration;

    Switch(Configuration configuration) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }
    
    void on() {
        configuration.enable();
    }
    
    void off() {
        configuration.disable();
    }
}

P.S. As you rightly noted, the order of decoration can matter. It is important to think about this at the time of decoration and at the time of providing the possibility of dynamic on/off.
In general, when developing a decorator, the most important thing is to adhere to the interface - so that the user of the decorator interface does not have any surprises (for example, if the interface method returns centimeters, and some decorator "violates" this interface and starts returning millimeters).
